# I try make a Graphic calculator but receive this error

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, calculator

I try to make a Graphic calculator but receive an error
I check everything but my program isn't working

> what is the problem of geometry types?

here are my codes

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import *
#============================= Main =============================
window = Tk()
window.geometry(650*825)
window.title('Calculator')
window.resiable(width=False,height=False)
window.configure(bg = 'gray')
photo_bg = PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Desktop\Captudsdre.png')
label_bg = Label(window,image=photo_bg)
label_bg.place(x=100,y=150)
```

and here is the error.

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\v.s.code projects> & "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" "c:/Users/Lenovo/v.s.code projects/file.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\v.s.code projects\file.py", line 5, in <module>
    window.geometry(650*825)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2073, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "536250"
```

please, anyone, tell me what is going wrong with board geometry and how can I correct the error?

Comment: typing `650*825` will multiply those literal numbers before passing the result to the `window.geometry` function. That function instead wants a string (with single or double quotes) to represent the window size, and an "x" rather than "*": `window.geometry("650x825")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
window.geometry(“650x825”)
```

As explained by [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220135/aaron) in a comment:

> typing `650*825` will multiply those literal numbers before passing the result to the `window.geometry` function. That function instead wants a string (with single or double quotes) to represent the window size, and an "x" rather than "*": `window.geometry("650x825")`

Because in python `650*825` is multiplication, so you're just passing their product and the [`.geometry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tk-option-data-types) function expects a string that is `"widthxheight"`